# Java selenium get copy of webelement

Tags: selenium

Is it possible to get a copy of the current state of a WebElement with selenium? I want to read an element that has a lot of other elements with data inside that constantly change. So when I read it I start to read the data from the elements inside but then the data of some other elements (which I have not read yet) change and I need to get the data of all elements at the same time. I tried using the innerHTML but then I would have to parse it manually.

Comment: Dynamic content was my nightmare when working with selenium. I solved this with creating pojo object which has similar atrs like WebElement (tagName, position, size, text, attributes, etc.). You need just to convert WebElement to your custom pojo and work with those pojos instead of WebElements directly.

Comment: The WebElement is actually a unique reference to an element in the DOM along with methods to get at data.  It's not the actual data, so you can't get all the data at once.  The innerHTML or page source would be something you could use to sort of freeze everything.  (I'm assuming you've got a frequently polling javascript or websockets here that updates DOM?)  You might find it easier to use something like Panda to parse the HTML.  The idea of using pojos would work if you can get at all the data fast enough.  (Depends on how "live" the DOM is... )